# verificar se elemento de array possui uma letra

Tags: javascript, node.js

Preciso de um algoritmo que leia um vetor, e me retorne se em um dos itens possui uma letra... se um dos itens tiver uma letra, eu quero que ele me retorne "qualitativo", caso todos os elementos tenham apenas numeros, quero que ele me retorne "quantitativo"... fiz um esquema dele apagar a virgula e o ponto para que não haja confusão na hora d verificar se possui apenas numeros ou letras caso o usuario entre com numeros decimais usando tanto ponto ou virgula... mas enfim, se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço muito... esse codigo está rodando perfeitamente no Navegador do chrome, mas quando eu tento usar ele num trabalho da minha faculdade em NODEJS, ele nao roda... a, e detalhe kk os elementos do vetor chegarão até mim todos em string... será que alguem sabe me explicar tmb o motivo do codigo rodar no navegador e em node js nao? Desde já, agradeçoo

var meucarro = ["19.98", "993", "228", "opala"];

```
    function verIsNaN(vetorEntrada) {
        var vetor = vetorEntrada
        var er = /^[0-9]+$/;
        let resposta = "quantitativa"
        for (let i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++) {
            if (vetor[i].indexOf(","))
            vetor[i] = vetor[i].replace(/[,.]+/g, '');

            if ((er.test(vetor[i])) === false) {
                resposta = "qualitativo"

            };
        }
        console.log(resposta)

    }


    verIsNaN(meucarro);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var meucarro = ["19,98", "993", "228", "opala"];

function verIsNaN(arr) {
    // Substitui vírgulas por pontos (Necessário para usarmos a função Number())
    let ar = arr.map(item => {
        if (item.indexOf(',') > -1) {
            return item.replace(',', '.');
        }
        return item
    });

    // Verifica se todos os elementos do array podem ser convertidos em Number
    // Caso um dos items não possa ser convertido, isto é, possui um caractere não numérico
    // O comando if recebe valor false
    if (ar.every(item => Number(item))) {
        return 'Quantitativo';
    }

    return 'Qualitativo';
}

console.log(verIsNaN(meucarro));
```